# PHP y SQL Server. No registra información en una de las tablas

Tags: php, sql-server, php5

Tengo un sistema en `PHP` y `SQL Server`, todo en el sistema funcionaba bien, pero de un momento a otro el sistema dejó de almacenar la información en una de las tablas. He buscado el problema en el código y todo parece estar bien..

Este es el método que uso para almacenar la información:

```
public function Registrar(){
    $ins = "'".$this->_rev_referencia."'";
    $ins .= ",'".$this->_rev_usuario."'";
    $ins .= ",'".$this->_rev_unidades."'";
    $ins .= ",'".$this->_rev_fecha_inicio."'";
    $query = 'INSERT INTO Revisados (referencia,usuario,unidades,fecha_inicio) VALUES ('.$ins.')';  
    $this->_db->Query($query);
    if($this->_db->FilasAfectadas()>0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Es este es un fragmento de la clase conexión, que muestra la conexión, y los 2 métodos que se ejecutan al realizar el registro de la información:

```
 public function DB(){
        $this->_server = SERVER;
        $this->_user = USER;
        $this->_passwd = PASSWD;
        $this->_database = DATABASE;
        $this->_port = PORT;
        try {
            $connectionInfo = array("Database"=> $this->_database, "UID"=> $this->_user, "PWD"=> $this->_passwd, "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
            $this->_conexion = sqlsrv_connect($this->_server,$connectionInfo);
            if($this->_conexion){
                    return true;
            }else{
                    echo("Ocurrió un problema al contenctar con SQL Server: <br>");
                    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }

        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function Query($query){

        $this->_result = sqlsrv_query($this->_conexion,$query);

    }

    public function FilasAfectadas(){

        return sqlsrv_rows_affected($this->_result);

    }
```

El problema es que el método Registrar esta recibiendo bien la información, pero no importa lo que haga, siempre recibo el **error:**

> **Warning:  sqlsrv_rows_affected() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...**.

Pero al ponerle un "echo" a la consulta me muestra por ejemplo:

```
"INSERT INTO Revisados (referencia,usuario,unidades,fecha_inicio) 
 VALUES ('2051346 111M','admin','1','2018-04-13 15:37:01')"
```

y esta consulta insertada directamente en `SQL Server` ejecuta bien.

No se mucho de `SQL Server` por lo que no se si el `SQL Server` sea la causa del problema.

Lo curioso es que el sistema funcionaba bien y actualmente todo lo demás funciona excepto este método y recurro a sus conocimientos por que ya no se que mas hacer con este problema.

De antemano, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: actualizaste php  o la base de datos?

Comment: Deberías revisar la configuración del server, antes de qué te funcionaba?.. segundo por favor coloca el stack completo de la excepción para ve bien por donde pasa ya que a veces el primer mensaje es genérico. 

Fijate acá hablan que es por la concatenación:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343796/warning-sqlsrv-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given] capaz y es lo mismo.